# Snips Nlu Language Resources issue

Tags: python, chatbot, snips

I'm trying to build a chatbot using Snips NLU installed on my computer, but when I download the Languages resources this message appears:

[Languages resources not linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGNLR.png)

when trying to run the Quickstart from https://snips-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html  this error shows:

[Language Resource Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRags.png)

I would like to know what I am doing wrong or if I did a bad installation.

Also I want to use Spanish and English resources for different projects.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some permission issue, as it seems that you are not using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

The snips-nlu lib creates a symbolic link after resources are downloaded, which requires sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be in your error itself. You simple need to run the below command on terminal

```
python -m snips_nlu download en
```

This will install the english dictionary resource which you have requested in your code.

Hope this helps :)